# How to resolve No module named 'hmmlearn' error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, hmmlearn

I'm new to hmmlearn and am trying to use the Jupyter Notebook to work through this [Gaussian HMM of stock data example](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_hmm_stock_analysis.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-hmm-stock-analysis-py). However, when I run the following code, I get an error.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import datetime

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm, pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, MonthLocator
try:
    from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl
except ImportError:
    # For Matplotlib prior to 1.5.
    from matplotlib.finance import (
        quotes_historical_yahoo as quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl
    )

from hmmlearn.hmm import GaussianHMM


print(__doc__)
```

The error is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-02bbde14d4d4> in <module>()
     14     )
     15 
---> 16 from hmmlearn.hmm import GaussianHMM
     17 
     18 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hmmlearn'
```

I have spent a while searching the Internet and trying to find out why this is happening. I've ensured that I've downloaded the dependencies (scikit-learn, numpy and scipy), and I've run `pip install -U --user hmmlearn`, both via the Windows cmd and as mentioned [here](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn). However, I keep getting the same error. I'm not sure if it may be something to do with the location of the different packages on my computer (I'm using Windows).

Does anyone have suggestions on what I could try to solve this? (My main aim is just to be able to get set up with hmmlearn so that I can start using it to explore HMMs.)

Comment: do you have more than one python in your computer ?. Can you import hmmlearn on the shell ?

Comment: I have both python 2 and 3. I'll try import hmmlearn on the shell.

Comment: Check the import in both shells, py2 and py3

Comment: When I ran `import hmmlearn` on the python 2 shell, it seemed to run. Nothing was returned and the prompt showed up as usual. When I ran `import hmmlearn` on the python 3 shell, I got the same error as I've posted in my question. Any suggestions?

Comment: If your code was run with py3, then this explain the problem.  you should install hmmlearn also on py3. maybe using pip3 instead of pip

Comment: I'll try that and let you know the result.

Comment: @CKKOY did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This [page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#hmmlearn)  provides 32- and 64-bit **Windows** binaries of many scientific open-source extension packages for the official CPython distribution of the Python programming language.

Select the appropriate file according to your system requirements. (For me, it's python 3.7 and windows 64 bit)

After you downloaded this, open command prompt in the same folder with .whl file and type:

```
pip install hmmlearn-0.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Then you can use **hmmlearn** in the *Jupyter Notebook* like that:

```
import hmmlearn
# Or 
from hmmlearn import hmm
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to run 'pip install hmmlearn' directly in the notebook cell. After that I restarted the kernel and it worked for me. Try to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even after doing all things ***no module named 'hmmlearn'*** is still showing in jupyter notebook.

first try to directly **install or run** below code In single Cell of opened file in your jupyter notebook.

```
pip install hmmlearn
```

Then you can run:

```
from hmmlearn import hmm
#or
import hmm
```

Comment: is this a solution?

Comment: Just so others know, behind-the-scenes this equates to `%pip install hmmlearn` because automagics is on be default in general. So in general you'd explicitly run `%pip install <package name>` as best practice in modern Jupyter. The use of the magic install commands, there's one for conda as well, work everywhere in the modern Jupyter ecosystem, such as JupyterLite and Google Colab now. (In other words use the magic symbol or no symbol in front of the commands so that the magic version is used. You don't want to use an exclamation point in conjunction with install commands in modern Jupyter.)